Принять json в action asp.net mvc , обработать и вернуть json на фронт
Как принять файл json в методе контроллера, обработать его и вернуть?
Сам проблемный контроллер, который естественно не работает) :
public JsonResult GetJsonFile(data???)
{
    var My_D1 = data2.D1 + 1;
    var My_L1 = data2.L1 + 1;
    var My_L2 = data2.L2 + 1;

    List<int> MyValue = new List<int>() { My_D1, My_L1, My_L2 };

    JsonSerializer(MyValue);//???

}

И для полноты инфы добавлю код с js (по нему вопросов нет)
async function preliminaryCalculation() {
    console.log("preliminaryCalculation starting Working!");

    //сам объект js
    const objetcValueForBilletir = {
        D1: D1_ValueForBilletir,
        L1: L1_ValueForBilletir,
        L2: L2_ValueForBilletir
    };
    
    return objetcValueForBilletir;
}
async function fetchData(data) {

    const url = "/Home/GetJsonFile";

    try {
        // преобразование данных в json и передача их на сервер, в действие/ action
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),   // объект в json
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });

        if (response.ok) { // если HTTP-статус в диапазоне 200-299
            // получаем тело ответа
            const json = await response.json();
            console.log("Успех:", JSON.stringify(json));
        } else {
            console.log("Ошибка HTTP: " + response.status);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Ошибка:", error);
    }
}

const btn = document.querySelector('goToConvertJson');

// нажатие на кнопку "Предварит расчёт"
//  должно происходить преобразование данных в json и передача их на сервер, в действие/ action
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const data = await preliminaryCalculation();
    await fetchData(data);

});

